# Android Glide: Show a blurred image before loading actual image

Tags: android, android-glide

I am developing an Android app which displays full screen images to the user. Images are fetched from the server. I am using Glide to show the image. But I want to display a very small size blurred image before displaying the actual image. Once the image is cached, directly full sized image should be shown.

Image Displaying flows goes like this:
- If image is downloaded for the first time, first download a small scaled image, and then download full resolution image.
- If image has been downloaded before, directly show full scale image.

I cannot find any method in Glide library, which tell me if a file exist in cache or not.

Any idea, how this can be done.

Answer (score 15):

```
Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                        .load(Your Path)   //passing your url to load image.
                        .override(18, 18)  //just set override like this
                        .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                        .listener(glide_callback)
                        .animate(R.anim.rotate_backward)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(image.score);
```

Comment: You are great boss...:)

Comment: @Hiren I'm getting a `cannot resolve method 'override(int, int)'` erorr

Comment: Amazing Answer, Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't download the whole image and then scale it down?

Answer (score 14):

with Glide v4:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(URL)
    .thumbnail(0.1f)
    .into(image_view)
```

Answer (score 5):

Better you can get idea from this Library or Use this library.

2 ways to do Blur and Original image in Android.

1) Initially load Blur Image Server URL path and once get success bitmap caching mechanism to load Original(Large) Image Server URL path.

Point 1 is possible, I got answer for you( Ask your server team to get Blur image or Low quality image to make blur and then load large image).
[APK Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8sf1DQSwIydT0RUUTlzM3N1QzQ/view?usp=sharing)

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(image.getMedium())
            .asBitmap()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                    // Do something with bitmap here.
                    holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Log.e("GalleryAdapter","Glide getMedium ");

                    Glide.with(mContext)
                            .load(image.getLarge())
                            .asBitmap()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                                    // Do something with bitmap here.
                                    holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                    Log.e("GalleryAdapter","Glide getLarge ");
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
```

2) Fresco by Facebook is a new image library for Android. Here’s the official blog post introducing the library. It supports the streaming of progressive JPEG images over the network which can be really helpful to display large images over slow connections. One can see the image gradually improve in quality.

[Progressive JPEGs with Facebook Fresco](http://arjunu.com/2015/05/progressive-jpegs-with-facebook-fresco/)

Answer (score 2):

You must have a small-size and a full-size image on your server. You can use [Firebase Resize Image Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images) if you are using Firebase as your backend. Once you have a small-size image URL and a full-size image URL you can use Glide like this:

```
            Glide.with(context)
            .load(fullSizeImageUrl)          
            .thumbnail(
                Glide.with(context)
                    .load(smallSizeImageUrl)
            ).into(imageView)
```

You'll get that blurry effect as the small-size image will be blurry

> ***According to Glide Doc***:
> .thumbnail()
> loads and displays the resource retrieved by the given thumbnail request if it finishes before this request. Best used for loading thumbnail resources that are smaller and will be loaded more quickly than the full size resource. There are no guarantees about the order in which the requests will actually finish. However, if the thumb request completes after the full request, the thumb resource will never replace the full resource.

Answer (score 1):

Use BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize to make a downsampled version of the image, and upload **both** versions. Load the sample image (which should take less time) and when the bigger version is downloaded, switch to that. You could also use a TransitionDrawable to make a fade transition.

Answer (score 1):

*this is not a perfect way but it will be easiest way to make it.*

**make placeHolder image as blur and set it into glide. then always it will show blur image and then after load the actual image it will appear.**

you can refer this code to use glide.

```
//crete this method into your Utils class and call this method wherever you want to use.
//you can set these placeHolder() and error() image static as well. I made it as comment inside this method, then no need to use [placeHolderUrl and errorImageUrl] parameters. remove it from this method.
public static void loadImage(final Activity context, ImageView imageView, String url, int placeHolderUrl, int errorImageUrl) {
    if (context == null || context.isDestroyed()) return;

    //placeHolderUrl=R.drawable.ic_user;
    //errorImageUrl=R.drawable.ic_error;
        Glide.with(context) //passing context 
                .load(getFullUrl(url)) //passing your url to load image.
                .placeholder(placeHolderUrl) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
                .error(errorImageUrl)//in case of any glide exception or not able to download then this image will be appear . if you won't mention this error() then nothing to worry placeHolder image would be remain as it is.
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) //using to load into cache then second time it will load fast.
                .animate(R.anim.fade_in) // when image (url) will be loaded by glide then this face in animation help to replace url image in the place of placeHolder (default) image.
                .fitCenter()//this method help to fit image into center of your ImageView 
                .into(imageView); //pass imageView reference to appear the image.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

glide has a direct way of doing this :

```
val thumbnailRequest = Glide.with(this)
        .load("https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=0")

Glide.with(this)
        .load("https://picsum.photos/2000/2000?image=0")
        .thumbnail(thumbnailRequest)
        .into(imageThumbnail)
```

from the [blog](https://proandroiddev.com/progressive-image-loading-with-rxjava-64bd2b973690):

> Thumbnails are a dynamic placeholders, that can be loaded from the Internet. Fetched thumbnail will be displayed until the actual request is loaded and processed. If the thumbnail for some reason arrives after the original image, it will be dismissed.

Answer (score -2):

use [BitmapFactory.Options.inSamleSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) to load a downsampled version of the image. Then load the bigger image and do a fade transition using a [TransitionDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html)

Hope this will Helps you ! Cheers !

Comment: But in this case, I need to download the big image, and I will have nothing to display until the image is downloaded\